# How to properly configure app.yaml to serve JavaScript files as text/javascript?

Tags: google-app-engine, http-headers, mime-types, app.yaml

JavaScript files are being served as text/plain in App Engine, regardless of what I do to change that:

'content-type' header media type value should be 'text/javascript', not 'text/plain'.

Anyone have any insight into what I'm doing wrong and how to get these to show up as the appropriate type?

I have three .js files in a 'static' subdirectory off of the main project. I've tried a few different ways to configure this, but nothing seems to work.

app.yaml:

```
- url: /(.*\.js)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/.*\.js
  mime_type: text/javascript
```

I tried specifying them individually.
(for static/script.js:)

```
- url: /static/script\.js
  static_files: static/script.js
  upload: static/script\.js
  mime_type: text/javascript
```

also

```
- url: /static/store.js
  static_files: static/store.js
  upload: static/store.js
  mime_type: application/javascript
```

I've also tried setting it in the html:

```html
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Everything works, but I'm getting errors about the javascript files being the wrong MIME type on every page, as well as "Response should include 'x-content-type-options' header." for every file accessed by each page.

I finally was able to remove most of the x-content-type-options errors by adding 'http_headers' as below, but then all scripts from the .js files are refused because they're not registering as the correct MIME type.

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  http_headers:
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Thanks in advance for any insights you can provide!

*Update
Flask mime type configuration:

```py
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')

app.config['MIME_TYPES'] = {
    '.js': 'text/javascript'
}
```

Comment: If you omit the `mime_type` altogether, the file extension `.js` determines the MIME type. Try that and see if the problem resolves.

Comment: I only began using mime_types because it wasn't recognizing the type by the file extension. Specifying the mime_types doesn't seem to make any difference anyway, so I've removed all references to that and it's behaving exactly the same.

Comment: This typically occurs with NodeJs. The issue is usually how content is being returned by code. If you're using NodeJs, include code where the contents of your JS is to be returned in your post.

Comment: I'm using a Python back end. The content in question is only being returned when an html file is calling for the associated .js file. As I understand it, aside from the app.yaml, the only thing that calls the .js files for the html files is the Flask app, which hands everything over to Apache via the app.yaml when the project is deployed. There's no issue when I serve it locally, but I did add a few lines in the Python code (added above) to configure mime types for Flask, also to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you didn't use `dev_appserver.py` when testing locally, then you didn't actually test the contents of `app.yaml` file which might be why it worked locally
2. For python, all you need in your `app.yaml` file is something like this

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
```

Note that the value of `static_dir` depends on the location/path of the `static` folder with respect to your project root folder

Comment: My app.yaml had little more than 
`handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static`
to begin with. And no, I don't expect it to have an effect when running the project locally. It's because of the warnings I get after I deploy the project that I've been adding things to the app.yaml to adjust the header information. 
Weird thing is, the warnings went away for about a day (in Edge, btw) and then came back on only some of the pages, and there were no changes during that time. 
Meanwhile, the Chrome dev tools don't register any issues like that at all. 
As long as it works, I'm good, I guess